# How do I hide Ribbon in Page Viewer WP, but not the default one?

Tags: css, ribbon, sharepoint-on-prem, page-viewer-web-part

I have added a Page Viewer Web Part to a default.aspx page and included the url to DispForm.aspx?ID=1 for a list.

However, I don't want the ribbon for DispForm to be displayed in the PVWP.

If I add a Script Editor Web Part with the following CSS, both the Ribbon for DispForm.aspx (within the PVWP) and the Ribbon for Default.aspx is removed.

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-ribbonrow {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to remove only the ribbon within the Page Viewer web Part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `DispForm.aspx` and add content editor web part (or script editor).

Put the following script inside:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(function(){
    if(getParameterByName('hide')){
      var ribbon = document.getElementById('s4-ribbonrow');
      ribbon.style.display = 'none'; 
    }
});

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

In your page viewer put following url:  `DispForm.aspx?ID=1&IsDlg=1&hide=1`

#### How does it work

The script on `DispForm` watches if url contains `hide` query param. If so, ribbon is hided. Javascript-only solution, no jquery required.

Comment: Thank you very much! The suffix to the url and the script editor on Dispform.aspx solved the problem. Now the page viewer looks exactly like I wanted it.